# CakePHP 2.x: date input with empty option/values

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have a date input and I wish to have the first option empty or blank. That way the user will have to select something, if not, validation will pick it up.

By default today's date preselected on load. I have managed to input a blank value but I cannot get it as the selected option.

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_of_birth', array('empty' => ''));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use boolean on `empty` attribute:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_of_birth', array('empty' => true));
```

Comment: I came here after setting `'empty' => true` but finding that page refreshes were still keeping a set value displaying. Here 'F5' will keep the keep the existing value in the dropdown. Instead you need to go to fully reload the page by selecting the address bar and hitting enter.